# Boot to Ubuntu on USB without having to reset BIOS every time

Tags: grub2, usb, bios

I have successfully installed full Ubuntu on a USB 3 stick drive.

I mainly use Win 10 but my aim is to be able to boot into the Ubuntu stick drive by simply plugging the stick in before booting.

I have set the boot priority order in BIOS to Ubuntu stick > Windows boot Controller > etc etc

However, when I boot to Ubuntu and wish to return to a Win 10 by removing the USB stick and rebooting the system requests a Grub response. Then I have to reboot change the boot order in BIOS to Windows > Ubuntu.

Is there a way to occasionally boot to the Ubuntu stick without having to continually reset boot order in BIOS ?

Comment: You may have inadvertently installed grub in the internal UEFI partition when you created the USB installation.

Comment: Know that it is a pain, but think removing grub from computer and putting it on USB might be a bigger pain unless you know what you are doing.  Think it is also a bug in installer that wants to put grub on computer main/first drive instead of an external drive.

Comment: Some BIOS makers allow you to press F12 at boot time and get a list of boot devices that would save you the troubles.